# Laravel project can not run in local environment

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel project. Now it is running on Cpanel, but I want to run this project in my local environment. When I step this project into a local environment, I got the 500 internal server error. Could you please help me resolve this issue and attach my project to this? https://github.com/sachinda96/MBPos

Comment: how are you trying to run the project?? with artisan serve??

Comment: what is the error 500 ? check your logs

Comment: set APP_DEBUG in .env to true and check error

Comment: also check log file for check error

Answer (score 0):

Please check your public folder, it's missing a lot of files. Eg. index.php.

And make sure your .env file (which is not uploaded, hence I can't diagnose the problem) is configured to run locally.

Crosscheck with a fresh local installation of laravel. Read more on how to install here at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation). :)

Comment: But this project properly working in Cpanel

Comment: Yeap, I can see that. It doesn't hurt to crosscheck for missing files with a local installation of Laravel. Also imo, if you really can't find the problem, just install a local Laravel, and copy your migrations, models, controllers etc over and do it

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the server (Apache, nGinx) logs
2. Check the Laravel logs
3. Make sure you have run `composer install` command
4. If you are on Unix OS, check permissions.

Comment: can i run this project using Xampp?

Comment: Sure you can. You can also try to use Laravel serve (`php artisan serve`).

Answer (score 0):

As long as your .ENV is configured to run your project locally, you should be fine.

Try running `php artisan serve` in your console.

Please read the [getting started docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#getting-started-on-windows).

Comment: Yes I have run PHP artisan serve but got 500 internal server error

Comment: Could you set `APP_DEBUG` in your .ENV to `true` and add this error to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but in my case, Sail wasn't running because I inadvertently closed Docker Desktop and Sail can't run without it.

So if you use Sail for your local development environment, maybe the answer is as simple as starting up Docker Desktop and then running the Sail up command to get the server running again.

I've created a Sail alias to make it easier to run Sail commands. Look it up if you don't know what it is. Once you have the alias created, you can start Sail with this simple CLI command...

$ sail up -d

Note: The -d flag simply tells it to start up in the background so it doesn't take over your terminal window. I'm on a Mac with Laravel v9.